# @escaping () -> Void does not work as expected in Mojave

Tags: swift, macos

I am developing a macOS app (Swift/Storyboard - [RsyncOSX](https://github.com/rsyncOSX/RsyncOSX)) and I have experienced a strange issue on Mojave. It is a user who reported this, I am developing on Catalina (and Big Sur). The class executes a Process object and is listening for two notifications within the `func executeProcess`. There are two `@escaping functions` which are executed every time the notifications occurs. This works fine on Catalina and Big Sur, but not on Mojave. Previous versions was utilizing protocols and delegates..

```
class RsyncProcessCmdClosure: Delay {
    // Process termination and filehandler closures
    var processtermination: () -> Void
    var filehandler: () -> Void
    // Verify network connection
    ...
    // Observers
    weak var notifications_datahandle: NSObjectProtocol?
    weak var notifications_termination: NSObjectProtocol?
    // Arguments to command
    ...

    func executeProcess(outputprocess: OutputProcess?) {
        ...
        let outHandle = pipe.fileHandleForReading
        outHandle.waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify()
        // Observator for reading data from pipe, observer is removed when Process terminates
        self.notifications_datahandle = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.NSFileHandleDataAvailable, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] _ in
            let data = outHandle.availableData
            if data.count > 0 {
                if let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
                    outputprocess?.addlinefromoutput(str: str as String)
                    // Send message about files
                    // ---> Execute closure
                    self?.filehandler()
                    if self?.termination ?? false {
                        self?.possibleerrorDelegate?.erroroutput()
                    }
                }
                outHandle.waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify()
            }
        }
        // Observator Process termination, observer is removed when Process terminates
        self.notifications_termination = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Process.didTerminateNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { _ in
            self.delayWithSeconds(0.5) {
                self.termination = true
                // ---> Execute closure
                self.processtermination()
                // Must remove for deallocation
                ...
        }
    }
    ...

    init(arguments: [String]?,
         config: Configuration?,
         processtermination: @escaping () -> Void,
         filehandler: @escaping () -> Void)
    {
        self.arguments = arguments
        self.processtermination = processtermination
        self.filehandler = filehandler
        ...
    }

    deinit {
        self.monitor?.stopMonitoring()
        self.monitor = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: "This works fine on Catalina and Big Sur, but not on Mojave" _What_ works fine but not on Mojave? You cannot just throw a whole bunch of code at us and say "broken". What line fails and how do you know?

Comment: Sorry about to much code... I have (on an old mac) reinstalled Mojave 10.14.6 and Xcode 11.3.1, compiled the code and the Process object does not react on the notifications when utilizing closures on Mojave. The exact same code utilizing delegates works OK on Mojave, but not with closures..

Comment: Reduced the code.. the closures are added to the class by init method, and they are called when the Process objects reads the two notifications... But not on Mojave...

Comment: Ok, so I _think_ you are saying: "`addObserver(forName:object:queue:)` doesn't work at all on Mojave." Is that the case? Can you test that hypothesis outside of this particular example?

Comment: Wait, I see a weakness in your code, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your code should *never* work. It's a mystery to me why it does.

You are saying

```
weak var notifications_datahandle: NSObjectProtocol?
weak var notifications_termination: NSObjectProtocol?
```

`weak`? I would expect anything assigned to these instance properties to be dropped immediately and so the notifications should never arrive.

Maybe something about internal management of notification observer objects prevents that on Catalina and Big Sur so you are just lucky there. But basically I would say delete `weak`. You are already using `weak self` in the closures so you've broken the retain cycle and you don't need to do anything else.

**EDIT** No, you're not! You forgot to use `weak self` in the second observer function:

```
self.notifications_termination = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Process.didTerminateNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { _ in
```

You need `weak self` there.

---

Note that you need to unregister the observer objects. Typically this will happen in `deinit`. You will call

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(notifications_datahandle)
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(notifications_termination)
```

You can then release the observer objects:

```
notifications_datahandle = nil
notifications_termination = nil
```

Comment: That make sense... I will remove the `weak` from observers and see what happens..

Comment: Cool, thanks. Of course if I'm totally wrong I can just delete this answer. :)

Comment: Well, by removing the `weak` from observers introduces a huge memory leak.. I will anyway test it again on Mojave and see what happens..

Comment: Okay, let me expand my answer to explain the right way to memory manage notification observers.

Comment: Okay so you forgot to use `weak self` in the second observer, that's your leak. I've added that to my answer too.

Comment: Thx, I have changed the code and the memory leaks is gone.. I did a test with just removing the `weak var` from the observers and compiled for Mojave, still does not work... I will make a new test with new code and see what happens..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221968/discussion-between-tevensen-and-matt).

Comment: I do not guarantee that notification observers work in Mojave Mac desktop applications. I presume they should, but I don't know it for a fact. All I did was to spot an obvious issue and describe how to fix that issue. What I suggest is that you should write a short test program, not using RsyncOSX, to see whether notification observers work _at all_ in Mojave. If they do, then perhaps the fault lies with RsyncOSX?